# How to send ENUM between forms?

Tags: c#, forms, enums

I'm trying to send an ENUM to another form with its constructor but failing at how to make both forms accep the same ENUM tried to declare same ENUM on both forms but it doesn't think they are same. Any suggestions appreciated.

```
public enum ROWERTYPE
{
    Alfa,
    Beta,
    Zeta
} 

Form3 form3 = new Form3(rowertype,x,y,z);

public enum ROWERTYPE
{
    Alfa,
    Beta,
    Zeta
}

public Form3(ROWERTYPE rowertype,int x,int y,int z)
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: Declare your enum in a separate file, reference that same enum from both forms. (So, add a new class file, named as your enum is. Delete the class declaration and add your enum. Remove from both forms.)
Also, if that's your real code how about renaming the variables so others that follow don't have to guess what "x" or "y" or "z" are.

Comment: Don't declare them twice. Put your enum outside the form. Just create a new file and put the enum in that.

Comment: @CodingYoshi what is the type of the file? i tried a new class but it didnt work well

Comment: @SimonWilson same answer above couldn tag u both in same comment.

Comment: Just choose a new class and name it your enum. It should work. If it doesn't work, let me know the error and I will tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Just click Project/Add Class name it RowerType. When it is created remove ALL code and paste in your enum definition above.

Comment: so i take 2 instances of the new class and use it as ENUM on forums is what u mean right?

Comment: No. Wait, I'll give you an example. Your don't create an instance of an enum, it's a const. You just reference the namespace of the enum with a using statement, then it will be available and in scope to use in both your Forms declarations.

Comment: Think of `ROWERTYPE` as being like `int` (because it is.) Where in your form is the definition of what an `int` is? Nowhere. The form doesn't declare or "own" `int`. The form only uses it. This is exactly the same, except that your enum is a custom type that you are declaring. You *could* put it inside the form class if only that form uses it. But it's more common to just declare enums outside of other classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this Wince...
[image]

Then your remove the 2 enum definitions from your Form3 and use this code below as your enum definition, change the namespace to match Form3's.

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
    public enum ROWERTYPE
    {
        Alfa,
        Beta,
        Zeta
    }
}
```

It's just a .cs file, it will get compiled and you can use the enum any where the namespace is imported. Think of an Enum as a collection of constants, you would only define one ROWERTYPE in your little app, but there is nothing to stop you declaring multiple enum instances called ROWERTYPE if they are in different namespaces...but, hella confusing if you did.

Comment: will try this in a moment kinda used the loophole way with int to get the thing running  while waiting for answer. I tried this initially as i stated in question but somehow when i tried to use it inside the form constructor it gave an error about something i dont recall now.

Comment: this WORKS now i have no idea why it didn't at first. Thank You.